# Create two columns from one to compare values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following problem. I have two columns, one contains measuring values and the other declares the state of the values (like actual state and desired state) Now I'm searching for a statement that creates an output where one column contains the measuring values with the actual state and a second column with the disired state values.

Thx in advance already.

For better understanding: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6N53sbrOHJuZFNSb2JDTlhscUU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share your code/sample data here. If it's too big, try cutting it down to the minimum required to understand the problem.

Comment: sorry, I can't, secret data. here is how I want it: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6N53sbrOHJuZFNSb2JDTlhscUU/edit?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something called pivotting:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html

Other recommended reading to brush up on your string concatenation techniques, where you'd also need some smart grouping and ordering:

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php

You'll find some nice tricks/methods there to do even much fancier stuff.

Comment: sorry, can'r enter your second link

Comment: Hmm, I could re-enter the link, but the first one is the most important one anyway.